# How to add actionbar white icon in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I'm trying to add `actionbar icon` into the android studio and i've do this:

Go to ImageAssets and set the icon for **Actionbar and TabIcons** and then refer that in menu icon.

But, it's a little bit black when the app compiled, like this:

[image]

as you can see, search icon is a little bit black.

So, what is the problem?

I've tried this with copy pasting the icon into drawable(without adding in `ImageAssets`) and it was white but, it's haven't any good resolution or quality.

How we can add a right or correct way for add actionbar icon like White color action icon into the actionbar?

Comment: Are you adding the search icon, or the three-dots icon, called overflow? Are you using appcompat?

Comment: I didn't read you solved.

Comment: it's okay buddy, by the way, i was trying to add this but android studio doesn't help and i'm already using Material icon plugin and it's ok now.thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, that plugin is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"` **Private resource**

And i think it's an android Studio bug which is when we are adding this, it's a little bit black.

Comment: You can post bugs to b.android.com if you think theres one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want white icon, select CUSTOM theme instead of holo dark or holo white when you import your asset and change color to #FFFFFF, or just manually copy it into drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable xxxhdpi

Comment: Did you try to copy the icon manually or set your accentColor to white?