# Where is Private resources like icons in Android studio?

Tags: android, material-design

i was trying to add search icon in actionbar and it's had a problem which is you can see that in below:

**[How to add actionbar white icon in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904042/how-to-add-actionbar-white-icon-in-android)**

So, the problem **was in the android studio** and i'm using `android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"`

BUT, I can't find anything about this name in `Sdk/platforms/res` So, for any icons in actionbar, i need to these icons name for adding it in my app.

Where should these **files/material icons** can be ?

Comment: those icons are provided by appcompat support library. you can use them if you are using appcompat in your project.

Comment: i now i can use it, but where is those icons?:) i need the name of those!

Comment: you can find them under Android-`SDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res` in this folder look for drawable folders.

Comment: @vrundpurohit - thank you, but, is it the complete icons? it seems those are not the full icons hoom?

Comment: I don't know man. which icon are you looking for?

Comment: for example this icon: https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_refresh

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you may be interested in adding the [Material Icon Plugin](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin) for Android Studio. I use it all the time.

Comment: @PPartisan - thanks, i will.But, let's say, Android studio haven't the **full icons** in `appcompat` and have a bug in `ImageAssets`.thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can find all icons here: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Each icon has png and svg version in all sizes. Just clone the repo and browse it using file explorer.

Comment: tnx, but if you see: `So, for any icons in actionbar, i need to these icons name for adding it in my app` that plugin solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the icons in Android Studio itself

Right Click mipmap folder and add a new Vector Asset.

Here you can find various icons which suit the one you want to use